# Problems with react-native-fbsdk: Login not working

Tags: javascript, facebook, react-native

I've been out of work for a while, and a friend who owns a startup company tasked me with fixing the Facebook Login functionality of his app.  Big opportunity for me.

None of the devs who built/worked on it are around anymore, and the app's code is written in such a confusing way.  So I'm bringing it here in hopes that I can get help to resolve it.

#### The Issue

When you open the app there's an intro screen, you close that, and then it prompts you to login with Facebook.

When `Login` is clicked, it loads for a bit, and then just returns back to the initial intro screen.

The debugger console displays:

```
[CodePush] Reporting binary update (2.0.0)
[CodePush] Report status failed: {"appVersion":"2.0.0"}
```

Not really familiar with CodePush, and I've been investigating that on and off, unsure if that's even related to my issue or not.  I went through their docs and made sure this project was configured right anyway.

Then I did the same with Facebook SDK.  I checked the docs and compared the instructions to what was done in the app, to see if the previous devs configured it properly.  Everything looks right.

Docs I'm referring to:
`https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/v2.2`

**NOTE** I can't do steps 5 and beyond, because you need to log in to complete those, and my FB account is not connected to the app.  Currently waiting to hear back from someone who worked on this.  Likely not relevant anyway, as everything else was done correctly.

I found the code for the Login Button in the codebase, but there's a lot of files importing to each other, and I'm not sure what exactly does what.  I will post the bread trail I followed below.

---

Here I track the Login button to find the source of the implemented feature.

I skip files that are unnecessary, such as the screen that displays the greeting along with the `Login` button.  I followed the import statements until I reached the following:

*LoginButtonContainer.js*

```
// @flow
import { connect }                  from 'react-redux'
import { loginWithFbButtonPressed } from '../redux/actions'
import LoginWithFbButton, {
  Props as LoginButtonComponentProps,
}                                   from '../components/LoginWithFbButton'    // <<<~~~ This file confused me, so next I checked here

type LoginButtonProps = {
  onPress: any => void,
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: any) => ({
  login: () => dispatch(loginWithFbButtonPressed()),
})

const mergeProps = (
  _,
  dispatchProps: { login: () => void },
  ownProps: LoginButtonProps
): LoginButtonComponentProps => {
  const { login } = dispatchProps
  const { onPress = () => null } = ownProps
  return {
    onPress: () => {
      onPress()
      login()
    },
  }
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps, mergeProps)(LoginWithFbButton)
```

*LoginWithFbButton.js*

```
// @flow
import * as React from 'react'
import { View, Text, Dimensions, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome'
import Entypo from 'react-native-vector-icons/Entypo'
import { heavyGray, lightGray, facebookColor } from '../constants/colors'

export type Props = {
  onPress: () => void,
  advisoryText: string,
}

/**
 * @class LoginWithFbButton
 * Facebook compliant component to login with FB, do not use any other medium to login with FB as to not break the TOS
 */
class LoginWithFbButton extends React.PureComponent<Props> {
  render() {
    const {
      onPress,
      advisoryText = `We don't post anything to Facebook`,
    } = this.props

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Icon.Button
          name="facebook"
          backgroundColor={facebookColor}
          onPress={onPress}
          style={styles.facebookButton}
        >
          Login with Facebook
        </Icon.Button>
        <View style={styles.advisoryContainer}>
          <Entypo
            color={heavyGray}
            name="info-with-circle"
            style={styles.infoIcon}
          />
          <Text style={styles.advisoryText}>{advisoryText}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

export default LoginWithFbButton
```

This led me to search for `<LoginWithFBButton>` but I do not see that anywhere in the app.

Despite me not finding that tag anywhere, the Login button is displayed on the screen.

Lastly(maybe) there's a file called `facebook.js`

*facebook.js*

```
// @flow
import FBSDK from 'react-native-fbsdk';
const { LoginManager, AccessToken } = FBSDK;

export type OpenFBLoginResult =
  | {
      fbData: string,
    }
  | {
      error: any,
    };
export type FacebookDataState = {
  accessToken: string,
  applicationID: string,
  declinedPermissions: Array<string>,
  expirationTime: number,
  lastRefreshTime: number,
  permissions: Array<string>,
  userID: string,
};

const getToken = (): Promise<?string> =>
  AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(t => (t ? t.accessToken : null));

const openFBLogin = (): Promise<OpenFBLoginResult> =>
  LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions([
    'public_profile',
    'email',
  ]).then(result => {
    if (result.isCancelled) {
      return {
        error: 'User cancelled Facebook login',
      };
    }
    return AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(fbData => ({
      ...result,
      fbData,
    }));
  });

const logOut = (): Promise<void> => LoginManager.logOut();

/**
 * Dummies
 */
class GraphRequest {}

const GraphRequestManager = () => ({
  addRequest: () => ({
    start: () => null,
  }),
});

const fetchUserImage = (facebookId: string) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const path = `/${facebookId}/picture`;
    // Create a graph request asking for user information with a callback to handle the response.

    const infoRequest = new GraphRequest(
      path,
      null,
      (error: ?Object, result: ?Object) => {
        if (error) {
          reject(error);
        } else {
          resolve(result);
        }
      }
    );

    // Start the graph request.
    new GraphRequestManager().addRequest(infoRequest).start();
  });
};

export default {
  openFBLogin,
  getToken,
  logOut,
  fetchUserImage,
};


// export function* openFBLogin(): OpenFBLoginResult {
//  type openFBLoginResultType = { +type: string, +token: string }
//  const response: openFBLoginResultType = yield call(Expo.Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync, FBAPP_ID, {
//      permissions: FB_PERMISSIONS
//  })
//  let error: ?any = null
//  switch (response.type) {
//      case 'success':
//          const { token } = response
//          yield call(_setFBToken, token)
//          yield put(actions.loginFb.success('', token))
//          return { token }
//      case 'cancel':
//          error = CANCELLED_ERROR
//          yield put(actions.loginFb.failure('', error))
//          return { error }
//      default:
//          error = JSON.stringify(response)
//          yield put(actions.loginFb.failure('', error))
//          return { error }
//  }
// }
```

This is probably not a great post, but a lot rides on this, and I'm hoping something obvious sticks out to someone more experienced than I.

If I've left anything out, I will update this post with whatever I can.  Thanks all.

Comment: can you try and uncomment the openFBLogin method in the last code block you shared above.

Comment: Hi thanks for replying.
Yeah, it breaks the app: "Can't find variable: openFBLogin"